# Laravel Auth::attempt() always false?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

I recently started learning Laravel (PHP MVC framework) and I've been having a lot of issues with Authenticating a user with: Auth::attempt($credentials).

I'll put my code snippets below. In my mySQL database I have a record with the following key=>values:
id=>1, username=>'admin', password=>'admin', created_at=>0000-00-00 00:00:00, updated_at=>0000-00-00 00:00:00

The Validator passes, but the Auth:attempt always fails.

If the code below and my little explanation isn't enough, please let me know! :-)

Routes.php:

```
Route::get('login', 'AuthController@showLogin');
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@postLogin');
```

AuthController:

```
public function showLogin(){

    if(Auth::check()){
        //Redirect to their home page
    }
    //Not logged in
    return View::make('auth/login');
}

public function postLogin(){

    $userData = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    $reqs = array(
        'username' => 'Required',
        'password' => 'Required'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($userData, $reqs);

    if($validator->passes() && Auth::attempt($userData)){
        return Redirect::to('home');
    }
    return Redirect::to('login')->withInput(Input::except('password'));
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe the attempt() method will hash the password that is sent in. Seeing as your DB entry's password is 'admin' in plaintext, that would fail. Save your password with Hash::make($password); and i believe your problem should be solved.

Comment: It worked! I rolled back all my migrations, made the Hash::make change to all the passwords, and ran a migration. You're a life saver! :D

Comment: Sweet, glad i could help! :) Would be nice if you could choose the answer as the correct one so i get some reputation :D

Comment: There you go! Thanks again :)

Comment: This really should be clearly stated in the Laravel documentation, as the only hint to this being the case is it stating that the password field must be 60 characters. It does not state that the Auth::attempt method (rightfully-so) hashes the password.

Comment: @MarkW You saved me, I missed the part about the password field being 60 characters in the documentation and due to that my attempts were always failing.. Thanks!

Comment: what if my password field has plain text? no encryption.