# cant login with Auth::attempt

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

RegisterController :

```
public function register(Request $request)
{

    $user=$request->file('cover');
    $destination ='img/user';
    $filename=$user->getClientOriginalName();
    storage::put('img/user/'.$filename,file_get_contents($request->file('cover')->getRealPath()));

    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $request->username;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->cover = $filename;
    $roles_id = DB::table('roles')->select('id')->where('rolename','admin')->first()->id;
    $user->roles_id = $roles_id;       

    $user->save();


}
```

Login.blade.php :

```
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}">

    <div class="row">      
    <div class="input-field col s6"> 
    <input type="text" class="validate" name="username" placeholder="username">                    
    </div>           
    </div>     

    <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input type="password" class="validate" name="password" placeholder="Password">                
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s5">
    <input type="submit" class="btn">
    </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

LoginController :

```
 public function postlogin(Request $request)
{                

   if(Auth::attempt([
       'username' => $request->username,
       'password' => $request->password
   ])){
       return 'Cool';
   }else{
       return 'Not Cool';
   }

}
```

just in case if you wanna see the route :

```html
Route::get('/register','Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@postlogin');
```

i do read this post [Laravel Auth::attempt() always false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006597/laravel-authattempt-always-false) but still dont know how to fix it

i try put

```
'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
```

and still got 'Not Cool'

:(

Comment: Try with `'password'=>bcrypt($request->password)` in the `if(Auth::attempt)`

Comment: yay it's you again :) 
i fixit when i change
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
To :              $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);

i  didnt know if bcrypt and Hash are different

Comment: I have provided a little explanation below to understand Hash::make(). Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's `Hash::make()` uses bcrypt internally to hash the passwords.

But `Hash::make()` will generate different hash each time. So you can't use `Hash::make()` again on the same password and compare the two values. It will always return `false` as the hash generated each time would be different. However Laravel provides a `Hash::check()` to check the passwords hashed using `Hash::make()` or `bcrypt()` helper function.

If you want to verify the password hashed by using `Hash::make()` or `bcrypt()` helper function then you can do so by

```
/*  Say you are using word secret as password while registering   */
$password = 'secret';

$hashedPassword = Hash::make('secret'); 

/*   Or   */

$hashedPassword = bcrypt('sectet');



/*   To verify the $hashedPassword - probably stored in a database   */
function verify_password($password)
{
    if(Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword)
    {
        echo "Passwords Match!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Passwords do not match :(";
    }
}

/*   While logging back (after registering)
    in the first attempt you have a typo in your password secrets instead of secret
 */
$attempt1 = 'secrets';
verify_password($attempt1);  /*   will echo Passwords do not match :(   */

/*   in the second attempt you use the correct password secret   */
$attempt2 = 'secret';
verify_password($attempt2);  /*   will echo Passwords Match!   */
```

Hope this helps to understand.